# Any ideas why Thinking Sphinx Rake tasks are not running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm finding that Thinking Sphinx sometimes errors out when I try to run its Rake tasks. Sometimes the tasks work fine, and sometimes I get errors like the one below.

I'm running the tasks as a normal user, not root. Not using sudo.

In the example below, searchd is still running after the Rake task fails.

I've also seen similar errors with `ts:rebuild`.

Has anyone else seen this?

I'm using Sphinx 0.9.9-release (r2117)

I'm using Thinking Sphinx 1.4.4 instead of the latest version because I'm on Rails 2.3.11.

---

```
$ rake ts:stop RAILS_ENV=production
(in /var/www/blog_app/releases/20110425053509)
rake aborted!
execution expired

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[ethan@apphost current]$ rake ts:stop RAILS_ENV=production --trace
(in /var/www/blog_app/releases/20110425053509)
** Invoke ts:stop (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:stop (first_time)
** Invoke thinking_sphinx:app_env (first_time)
** Execute thinking_sphinx:app_env
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute thinking_sphinx:stop
rake aborted!
execution expired
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thinking-sphinx-1.4.4/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:58
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/opt/ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/opt/ruby/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Were you running `rake ts:stop` from a capistrano deploy script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this error is caused when you have a search daemon already running.

Try

```
ps | grep searchd
```

if that gives you something like this...

```
73470 ttys002    0:00.03 searchd --pidfile --config /Users/dwickwire/Projects/production/config/development.sphinx.conf
81907 ttys002    0:00.00 grep searchd
```

then kill the searchd

```
sudo kill -9 process_id
```

process_id in my case would be 73470

Then try rake ts:rebuild again.

Comment: I would like to add, the '9' should only be included after a attempt without it has not been successful.  Thats just a good rule generally speaking.

Comment: This is not a solution. The purpose of `rake ts:stop` *is* to stop `searchd`. Saying that "you should manually kill searchd before running ts:stop" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Alex, rake ts:stop was already tried in this example, the issue here can be caused when two daemons are running and the stop doesn't know which one to stop.

Comment: OK, good point. But in the example you show, there is only one `searchd` daemon running. I am having the same problem as Ethan, but in my case, there is also only one `searchd` daemon running, and `ts:stop` can't stop it. Of course, I could keep manually killing it rather than using `ts:stop`, but that's not solving the actual problem.

Comment: I usually do in the following two steps:
sudo killall -9 search # will kill sphinx
RAILS_ENV=production rake ts:rebuild

Comment: I usually only pull out my nine when the baddies are around.

Answer (score 6):

I tried command 'ps | grep searchd' to get process ID, but I didn't get it.
Then I tried command 'pgrep searchd', it gives me process ID.
I killed that process and ran command 'rake ts:rebuild'. It worked.

I blogged about the entire experience [here](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/05/rake-tsrebuild-giving-execution-expired.html) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Answer (score 3):

In thinking_sphinx 1.4.4 there is a **5 second timeout** on `rake ts:stop`

If `rake ts:stop` takes close to or longer than 5 seconds, ruby will throw an exception.

I'm using the thinking_sphinx 1.3.18 in the meantime. (there is no timeout on 1.3.18).

Also I have submitted a patch to [the github repository](https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx) and the timeout will be configurable with a `sphinx.yml` configuration variable `stop_timeout`.

NOTE: `rake ts:rebuild` == `rake ts:stop; rake ts:index; rake ts:start`

Comment: stop_timeout variable is not working, as i tried setting it as 1 sec and rake not aborted.

Comment: @mirza yes that setting appears to not work anymore.

Comment: Any other solution , tried timeout: 1 too which did not work, I am stuck. I am using thinking-sphinx 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I guess after deploy by capistrano you didn't run `rake thinking_sphinx:configure`
it would generate sphinx config file in `config/production.sphinx.conf`

try add pidfile to `config/sphinx.yml`

```
production:
  ...
  pid_file: "/tmp/searchd.pid"
```

it will make sure to find pid of searchd to kill

and added following code to `config/deploy.rb`

```
namespace :my_tasks do
  task :generate_sphinx_config, :roles => [:web] do
    run "cd #{latest_release} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake thinking_sphinx:configure"
  end
end

....

after :deploy, "my_tasks:generate_sphinx_config"
```

to generate sphinx config file in each release folder

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

This problem occurs if your searchd crashed or you killed it manually. On Windows it doesn't overwrite your `searchd.<environment>.pid`, so still the old PID is saved and ThinkingSphinx doesn't check the real running processes in your taskmanager. So all these commands (`rake ts:restart, rake ts:rebuild, ...`) won't work, rake will always abort and you get the error `rake aborted, ... searchd already running`

**The solution**

Delete your `path-to/your-app/log/searchd.<environment>.pid`.

`<environment>` may be `development` or `production`, depending on your current stage.

Hope this answer will help the googler's.